# Python Django I want remove language code in url(path)

Tags: python, django, locale, django-i18n

I want remove language code in url

for example

select en
select jp
select cn
I want it to appear as www.abc.com instead of www.abc.com/jp, www.abc.com/cn.

I want to get language code from session and activate it. not url
help me

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('web.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

helpertags.py

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def change_lang(context, lang=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Get active page's url by a specified language
    Usage: {% change_lang 'en' %}
    """

    path = context['request'].path
    url_parts = resolve(path)

    url = path
    cur_language = get_language()


    try:
        activate(lang)
        url = reverse(url_parts.view_name, kwargs=url_parts.kwargs)
    finally:
        activate(cur_language)

    print("%s" % url)
    return "%s" % url
```

templates.html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                        {% for language in languages %}
                            <li><a href="{% change_lang language.code %}" class="btn-lang">{{ language.code }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Split it by a slash.

Comment: Don't use a template tag. Create a view to change language. That view should return a `HttpResponseRedirect` to the url without the language code. Just remove the language code from the `request.path` string.